# How to write into text file without deleting the data saved into the text file?

Tags: text, io, text-files

I created a program that will ask you "What is your name" and will save it on a text file but when you run the program again and enter a different name, ***the first entry will be deleted and the latest entry will be shown on the console.*** I want to make a program that every name the user typed will be saved on the text file without deleting any name from it. Im using **eclipse** by the way.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Sample
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner con = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;

        System.out.println("What is your name: ");
        name = con.nextLine();

        try
        {
            Formatter x= new Formatter("Sample.txt");
            File f = new File("Sample.txt");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f,true));
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(f);

            if(f.exists())
            {
                System.out.println("Done creating");
                out.println(name);
                out.close();
            }else
            {
                System.out.println("Failed");
            }

            while(scn.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = scn.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
                scn.close();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use BufferedWriter instead of PrintWriter.

Here is a good example:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-append-content-to-file-in-java/